# Button does not listen/work

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to detect if the button is clicked and store the value of a retrieved info in session from `def detail`.

**views.py**:

```
def job_display(request):
    job_list = Job.objects.filter(Publication_Status="A").order_by('-  Job_Position')
    context = {'job_list': job_list}
    return render(request, 'frontend/jobs.html', context)

def detail(request, job_id):
    jreq = get_object_or_404(Job, pk=job_id)
    if request.POST.get(jreq.Job_Position):
        request.session['jpos'] = jreq.Job_Position
        return HttpResponseRedirect('apply')
    return render(request, 'frontend/details.html', {'jreq': jreq})
```

**template**:

```
<h1>{{ jreq.Job_Position }}</h1>
<h2>{{ jreq.Job_Description }}</h2>
{{ jreq.Available_Slots }}
<ul>
{% for req in jreq.job_requirement_set.all %}
    <li>{{ req.Job_Requirements }}</li>
{% endfor %}
<p> BLA BLA BLA <p/>
{% for req in jreq.skill_requirement_set.all %}
    <li>{{ req.Skill_Requirements }}</li>
{% endfor %}

<input name="form-type " name = {{ jreq.Job_Position }} value={{ jreq.Job_Position }} type="submit"/>
```

Comment: What's wrong here? There is a traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to put your `<input>` into a `<form>`. Without a form you cannot `POST` any data.

Sounds like you need to learn how a form works in web development. While it's hard to give you a concrete example, django original document is always your friend: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/